# Jquery issue with Magento tabs

Tags: jquery, css, magento, tabs

I have installed the following extension for adding multiple contact forms on one website:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-formbuilder.html

The extension is breaking the layout of the products landing pages, in particular the tabbed content at the bottom of the page, which is visible.
The website with the extension installed is the following:

http://m.theseolounge.co.uk/index.php/industrial-scales/bench-scales/marsden-b-100-bench-scale.html

The live website without the installation is the following:
http://www.marsden-weighing.co.uk/index.php/marsden-b-100-bench-scale.html

Can someone point me in the right direction? Is it something I can solve by modifyin the CSS or is the website loading the wrong JQuery?

Comment: You should contact the module's developer and ask for their help. Without sharing your code here you probablt won't be able to get any help.

Comment: I did but I didn't get any reply..

Comment: I reviewed this page: http://m.theseolounge.co.uk/index.php/industrial-scales/bench-scales/marsden-b-100-bench-scale.html

it seems that there is error in js http://prntscr.com/c7pvr5

Comment: First you need to resolve this error than anyone can check for tabbing issue